# The code works but I am unable to make place vcn in a particular compartment

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, terraform-provider-oci

The code below works, but I am not able to add a -vcn at the end of the vcn name and also I am unable to make sure that the vcn sits in the compartment it is intended to sit in.

My variables.tf looks like -

```
#Compartment

variable "pv_compartment" {
  type = map(string)
  description = "Compartment Details"
}
variable "pv_enable_delete" {
  description = "enable duplicate check on compartment names and delete on destroy"
}
variable "pv_subtenancy_ocid" {
    description = "sub-tenancy ocid"
}

# VCN
variable "pv_vcn" {
  type = map(string)
  description = "VCN Details"
}
```

My main.tf looks like -

```
resource "oci_identity_compartment" "tf_compartment" {
    for_each = var.pv_compartment
    compartment_id = var.pv_subtenancy_ocid
    description = each.value
    name = each.key
    enable_delete = var.pv_enable_delete
}

resource "oci_core_vcn" "tf_vcn" {
    count = length(var.pv_vcn)
    cidr_block = values(var.pv_vcn)[count.index]
    compartment_id = element([for x in oci_identity_compartment.tf_compartment: x.id], count.index)
    display_name = keys(var.pv_vcn)[count.index]
}
```

My terraform.tfvars looks like -

```
pv_subtenancy_ocid = "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaa"
pv_compartment = {
  mngmt-compartment = "Management Services Compartment"
  app-compartment = "Application Compartment"
  dmz-compartment = "DMZ Compartment"
  db-compartment = "DB Compartment"
}
pv_enable_delete = "true"

#VCN Details
pv_vcn = {
  mngmt = "10.234.0.0/23"
  app = "10.234.10.0/23"
  dmz = "10.234.2.0/23"
  db = "10.234.16.0/23"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use concat like this:

```
${var.label_prefix}-${var.vcn_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kalyan

Your code is actually working well with very minor modifications - I tested it from cloud shell.

The mods I've done:

1. in terraform.tfvars used a compartment id instead of the tenancy ID in the variable `pv_subtenancy_ocid` (because I don't have access to create subcompartments under root). This may not be necessary in your case if you have rights to create resources (sub compartements) under root.
2. in main.tf, as suggested by @mrtaylor2112, added an interpolation like so
   `display_name = "${keys(var.pv_vcn)[count.index]}-vcn"`

With proper authorization and provider setup, the config builds and applies as expected, creating VCNs in their corresponding sub compartments.

Regards